# Why isn't my async Angular Jasmine unit test working?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test an asynchronous component method and I think I'm using the asynchronous testing capabilities of Angular 4 correctly, but it isn't working. My problem is that when I run the test, it **doesn't wait** for the Promise to resolve. It seems like the asynchronous nature of function is causing a timeout to be tripped and the test to be exited prematurely. The test will pass no matter what because all `expect()` statements inside `whenStable()` get skipped.

If I omit the `async()` wrapper function and switch to the Jasmine syntax of passing in a `done` callback and call it at the end of the `whenStable()` block,  it works correctly. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work with the Angular `async()` wrapper?

My code looks like this:

```
// my.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.getResults().then((results) => {
    this.results = results;
  });
}

// My asynchronous function, which takes 1.5s to load results
getResults() {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('foo');
    }, 1500);
  })
  return promise;
}


// my.component.spec.ts (Angular async version which doesn't work)
it('should load results', async(() => {
  spyOn(component, 'getResults').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('bar'));
  component.ngOnInit();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    // Everything in here gets skipped when I run the test
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // This should cause the test to fail, but it doesn't because it's not run in time
    expect(true).toBe(false)
  });
}));

// my.component.spec.ts (Jasmine version that works)
it('should load results', (done) => {
  spyOn(component, 'getResults').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('bar'));
  component.ngOnInit();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // This should fail and it does because the test works using Jasmine's "done" callback
    expect(true).toBe(false);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Try calling `fixture.detectChanges();` instead of `component.ngOnInit();` which will also run the `ngOnInit()`, since it is the first time you are calling it.

Comment: What is wrong here? https://plnkr.co/edit/MIDy85L9fVOtdvyXKnuS?p=preview You `getResult()` method won't be executed because you mock it

Comment: @AmitChigadani Thanks but that doesn't work. `expect(true).toBe(false)` still passes.

Comment: @yurzui Aha, your plunker helped me figure it out. This is what I was doing, and the problem was calling `fixture.detectChanges()` in my `beforeEach()`: https://plnkr.co/edit/57AX2VozvG2pzUEzJVZR?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @yurzui's Plunker, I determined that my problem was caused by my calling `fixture.detectChanges()` in my `beforeEach()` method:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    // The following line is to blame! Removing it makes the test work correctly.
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: Ever figure out why `fixture.detectChanges()` couldn't be in `BeforeEach()`

Comment: @AdamHughes It's because in my case I needed to prevent `ngOnInit()` from running. `detectChanges()` causes that method to run.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble dealing with this, we solved it by using the angular/testing async function in beforeEach :

```
beforeEach(async(() => { // <-- use async
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [AppComponent],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    // The following line is to blame! Removing it makes the test work correctly.
    fixture.detectChanges();
}));
```

... as the docs says : https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-async.